# Is it good practice to restrict the parameters of a constructor in the constructor?

Tags: java

So I want to make a social security class, and the input has to be in the following format

# # # - # # - # # # #

This is a string, and in my constructor i have the following code to check if its a proper method.

```
private static boolean checkSocialSecurityNumber(String s) {
        int positionOfFirstDash = 3;
        int positionOfSecondDash = 6;
        if(s.length() != 11) {
            return false;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if(i == positionOfFirstDash || i == positionOfSecondDash) {
                if( c != ('-')){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if(!Character.isDigit(c)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

This method works, but its inside the classes constructor declaration.

and I would throw a system error if it returns false.

Is this the proper way to do it? it just looks wrong to have that in my constructor. My question is how I go about forcing the proper input, not sure how else to do it?

Comment: You might consider using a regular expression for this validation.

Comment: "this method works, but its inside the classes constructor declaration" ... what?

Comment: Please specify what "good" means in your case.

Comment: For me, doing the check within the constructer seems ok. I don't have any literature references but in my opinion it makes sense to check it directly inside the constructor since this is the "place" where you  create/not create an object.

Comment: Yes it is a good practice to check the if the argument given to your constructor is correct. Plus there is no problem to call a subroutine inside a constructor. And finally, throwing an exception if the argument given does not fit the requirement is also a good practice. Conclusion : Your code is totally OK

Comment: @vincrichaud "no problem" not necessarily. You can invoke a method before fields it uses have been initialized. It's also problematic to invoke any overrideable method.

Comment: Also, and I don't often say this: your method would be much easier with regex: `s.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{3}")`.